# How to send a request using ajax when the server response after 10 sec?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I just want to send request to servlet and after some event happen the servlet will send a response
I think my problem in Ajax get request but here my servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", value = "/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet implements Observer {
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.response = response;
        Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
        //response when game start.
        int gameId = Integer.parseInt(cookie[2].getValue());
        Maze maze = register.gamePool.getGame(gameId);
        maze.getGameStatus().addObserver(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        GameStatus gameStatus = (GameStatus) o;
        if (((GameStatus) o).isGameStart()) {
            this.processResponse(gameStatus);
            o.deleteObserver(this);

        }
    }

    private void processResponse(GameStatus gameStatus) {
        String json = new Gson().toJson(gameStatus.isGameStart());
        try {
            if(!response.isCommitted())
            response.getWriter().write(json+"here is response in json");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/WNA_MazeGame_Online_war_exploded/Servlet",
        success: function (data, status) {
               alert("data:"+data+"\n");
        },

    });
});
```

basically the response will come from server any time (maximum 1 min ).

but when I try this the alert show immediately as the page lode with no data!

Answer (score -1):

You can debug your request using "error" function, then try to log your request in console.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/WNA_MazeGame_Online_war_exploded/Servlet",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json", //Specify response type from server 
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Success: " + result)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR, exception)
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: can i have more help plz :) its give me Object "parsererror"